# Pinterest like website invite system

Tags: looking-for-a-script

I'm looking for an invite system for a website. Something similiar to [pinterest.com](http://pinterest.com)'s where user put their email in and get after some days automatically an email send with the invitation link.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking codecanyon.net out for things like this,

I found 2 possibles that should do the trick but may need some simple minor edits might be required to make it send after X mins/hours.

- [Invite Manager](http://codecanyon.net/item/invite-manager/425292)
- [Registration System with Invitations](http://codecanyon.net/item/registration-system-with-invitations/603208)